# How to configure git diff for .odt files correctly? I get this error: fatal: unable to read files to diff

Tags: git, git-diff

I thought I had git configured to diff odt files correctly, but when I run `$ git diff <commit>` I get this error:

```
/usr/local/sbin/odt2txt: line 2: odt2txt.pl: command not found
fatal: unable to read files to diff
```

I've installed odt2txt. I'm on Gnu/Linux. I created a file called odt2txt and odt2txt contains this:

```
#!/bin/bash
odt2txt.pl "$1" -
```

I `$ chmod a+x` odt2txt and I put odt2txt in /usr/local/sbin

My .gitattributes looks like this:

```
*.ods diff=odf
*.odt diff=odf
*.odp diff=odf

*.ods difftool=odf
*.odt difftool=odf
*.odp difftool=odf
```

Then I ran `$ git config diff.odf.textconv odt2txt` to configure git to use odt2txt... and that is where I am now. I get the error above, when I try to `git diff`.
How do I fix this error?

Comment: Strange, in previous question you wrote that "git diff" works for you

Comment: Git diff currently works with microsoft word documents, but git diff no longer works with .odt files.
When I wrote the previous question, git diff worked for .odt files, because I did not have an odt2txt in /usr/local/sbin. Does that make any sense? I added the odt2txt wrapper script, in hope that it would make git difftool work on .odt files.

Comment: You should no longer need odt2txt if you save the .odt files as .fodt ("flat odt"). They will be much larger because they're not compressed, but they will have all the xml content without the zip archived directories of standard .odt files. I'm not sure when fodt support was added but it's been a part of LibreOffice for a number of years now.  EDIT: Nevermind I just realized you're probably diffing the text content and not the XML

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a file by making the call to a nonexistent `odt2txt.pl` file.

Instead, install odt2txt on Gnu/Linux and make sure you have `odt2txt` in your `$PATH`.